# DXL filter using if else loop

Tags: ibm-doors

I am using Door 9.6 and trying to create a generic filter which can be used for multiple documents in my project. 
The project documents have an attribute "Requirement Type". This attribute can have value as "Functional", "Non Functional", "Information" etc. 
The documents are not uniform and some of the documents have "Requirement Type" as "Functional", "Information" . 
I am trying to use attributeValue() to find out this variation but somehow couldn't figure out the issue in the code.

```
-E- DXL: <Line:16> incorrect arguments for (||)
-E- DXL: <Line:16> incorrect arguments for (||)
-E- DXL: <Line:16> undeclared variable (f1)
-E- DXL: <Line:16> incorrect arguments for (=)
```

Here is the code

```
Module m = current
load view("default view")

AttrDef ad = find(current Module, "Requirement Type")

    if (attributeValue(ad, "Non functional")){
        Filter f1 = contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Non Functional", false)
    }
    else {
        Filter f1= contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Functional", false)
    }

    Filter f2= contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Information", false)
    Filter f3= contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Functional", false)

    Filter set_f = f1 || f2 || f3
    set(current Module, set_f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is declared inside { brackets }, the variable will not be visible from the outside. Declare it outside the brackets, but set them inside.

```
Module m = current
load view("default view")

AttrDef ad = find(current Module, "Requirement Type")

Filter f1
if (attributeValue(ad, "Non functional")){
    f1 = contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Non Functional", false)
}
else {
    f1= contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Functional", false)
}

Filter f2= contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Information", false)
Filter f3= contains(attribute "Requirement Type", "Functional", false)

Filter set_f = f1 || f2 || f3
set(current Module, set_f)
```

Comment: I tried declaring "Filter f1 = current" but still getting an error "null Filter parameter was passed into argument position 1"

Comment: Adding @Mike for notification

Comment: ah, I really hate it that there are no mails sent out when comments are posted...

Comment: What is your current code? Your answers sound like your lines 8 and 11 look like "Filter f1 = contains(..." and not like "f1 = contains(...", i.e. it sounds like you redefine the filter variable inside the if and else blocks.

Comment: Realized the mistake. It worked...Thanks a ton @Mike  :) You are a champ